# Using custom fields in a ROS service

Tags: ros, pcl, service, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to create a service to handle point clouds. Ideally I'd use a `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>` but I'll even settle for `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`.

When I try and create my `service.srv` as:

```
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud_in
---
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud_out
```

I get

```
error: <class 'genmsg.base.InvalidMsgSpec'>: sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 is not a legal message field type
```

EDIT:

the correct format should be `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 cloud_in`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258123/using-custom-fields-in-a-ros-service/) by [MWrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/7271/mwrock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-03-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try changing sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 to sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.

---

Originally posted by [huanxiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28265/huanxiner/) with karma: 271 on 2017-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MWrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/7271/mwrock/) on 2017-03-28**:
that was a stupid mistake, thanks!